# Align image to right of text in div

Tags: html, css, image

I'm sure it's an easy question but I can't figure it out. 
I have this code basically

```
<div>
<img />
<p></p>
</div>
<div>
<img />
<p></p>
</div>
```

I want the image to align to the right of the text within the div. Everything I've tried so far takes the image out of the normal page flow making the div not respect the height of the image. I can't just explicitly state the height of the div because the image inside is dynamic and only of set width.

Here's what the page looks like.

[image]

How do I align the image to the right of the div and still have the div respect the height of the image.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your code in it? Without the needed code, we can't help

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oeqw8mfe/1/

Answer (score 4):

Basically your div must have `overflow:hidden`, look example:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden">
    <img style="float:right; width:100px; height:100px"/>
    <div>text text text text text text text text</div>
</div>
<div style="overflow:hidden">
    <img style="float:right; width:100px; height:100px"/>
    <div>text text text text text text text text</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can put `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after each `div`

Answer (score 2):

In css set the overflow of the div that has to respect the height of the image to auto.

```css
div {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ruven. Tried that, it's height: auto in the image. As the image is out of the normal flow it only sets the div to the height of the text hence the image spilling out the bottom of the box.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the float on the image. In order to fix this, you may use a method called **clearfix** on the container element: `div.infobox`

```
.infoBox:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oeqw8mfe/2/).

Comment: Now that's where I first started making edits! I think I was trying to apply the clear to img though and not the div as it was the img I was applying the float to.